# In Chromium-based browsers, when is the "http_allowed" key in Preferences updated?

Tags: google-chrome, microsoft-edge, chromium

I'm looking at the Preferences file in Chromium browsers data, and I'm trying to understand some of the entries I see there. My question is regarding the "http_allowed" key, and what causes it to be updated?
I've been trying to look for answers online, but I haven't found anything, even in the documentation.

Hoping theres some Chromium-geniuses out there that can help!

Comment: The source code might answer your question: https://source.chromium.org/chromium/chromium/src/+/main:components/security_interstitials/core/https_only_mode_allowlist.cc;l=58?q=http_allowed&ss=chromium%2Fchromium%2Fsrc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I made some tests with Edge browser and I found that it will add a record of the website in "http_allowed" after you visit HTTP-only website. That's when "http_allowed" key in Preferences updated.